# Obtain a float[] view of a byte[] array

Tags: java, arrays

I have some binary objects as `byte[]` and I need to convert them to `float[]` before performing some computations on them.

My current approach is the following:

```
bytes[] binaryData;
float[] docVector = new float[vectorSize];
ByteBuffer.wrap(binaryData).asFloatBuffer().get(docVector);
```

This does work, but as far as I understand *it creates a copy of the original array*, is it possible to get a float array that is pointing at the same memory address of the binary array? In python and numpy one can for instance do the following to get a view of the same data in memory:

```
import numpy as np
binary_data = np.zeros(40, dtype=np.uint8)
float_array = binary_data.view(np.float32)
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, my final approach to avoid unnecessary copying was to actually use C++ binded with the JNI. It did work but was much much more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible in java.

Only way to do something similar is to us [Flyweight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) pattern

**EDIT**

I used name "Flyweight" incorrectly (thanks to @AdrianShum).
What I meant is class like this:

```
class FloatArray {
    byte[] buff;
    void set(int index, float value) { ... }
    float get(int index) { ... }
}
```

Comment: I can hardly correlate Flyweight with this problem.

Comment: @AdrianShum imagine we have a class that have methods `getFloat` and `setFloat`, it means that it have interface similar to array. Inside this class we have reference to byte array. Each time we need to write float we convert it to bytes and store at corresponding indexes in byte array. Same with reading array. That pattern called flyweight.

Comment: The approach you describe is valid.  However imho this is not Flyweight.  Flyweight pattern is solving totally different problem (though the result MAY look a bit like what you describe)

Comment: @AdrianShum Yep. I used name incorrectly. It should have index attribute inside the class to be flyweight.

Answer (score 2):

Java is a heavy object oriented language. Aside from very few primitive types, everything in Java is an object.

Arrays in Java are no expcetion. Unlike other languages like C or C++, arrays are not simply allocated memory of primitive types. They are complete and full objects, inheriting from `java.lang.Object`.

This becomes obvious by this example code:

```
float[] foo = new float[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
byte[] bla = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
System.out.println(foo.getClass());
System.out.println(bla.getClass());
```

So, even if there was a way to reinterpret/cast a `byte[]` as a `float[]`, it would give you a corrupt object, as you aren't casting the underlying primite type array, but the entire object, and there is no guarantee that they are the same size or that the underlying data is stored at the same offset.

Since Java doesn't have a way to get two distinct array objects sharing the same underlying binary data, you have two options:

1. Create a copy. Since some (outdated) Java implementations create a copy when calling `ByteBuffer.toFloatBuffer()`, you might want to check if a copy has been created already:

   ```
   float[] docVector;
   FloatBuffer floatBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(binaryData).asFloatBuffer();
   if (floatBuffer.hasArray()) {
       docVector = floatBuffer.array();    // Avoids copying twice
   }
   else
       docVector = new float[vectorSize];
       floatBuffer.get(docVector);
   }
   ```
2. Depending on what you are doing, it might be enough to work with the `FloatBuffer` directly, instead of creating a new `float[]` array. You can iterate over the floats in a similar manner, depending on your use case and target platform this is a *memory vs performance* decision.

Comment: Thanks for answering! But I tried that already, when calling `asFloatBuffer()` the obtained buffer is not backed by an array and hence the `array()` function is not available.

Comment: This code throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Yeah just saw that it depends on the Java implementation. Seems that all the major ones don't allow access to the underlying byte array as float array. GNU Classpath allows it, but it's super outdated.

Comment: @MaxVollmer I curious about how they achieve it. They store data separate from array object header? It must be slow.

Comment: Their [FloatBufferImpl](https://opensource.apple.com/source/gccfast/gccfast-1614/libjava/gnu/java/nio/FloatBufferImpl.java) class uses a native cast. It might actually do a copy under the hood, I am not sure.

Comment: Yeah, nope, it makes a copy. It's obvious actually, as arrays are objects, not primitive types.

Answer (score -2):

You can read your bytes into an input stream and read floats from the input stream.

```
    byte [] bytesArray = new byte[120]; //array of your bytes.
    ByteInputStream bytesStream = new ByteInputStream(bytesArray, bytesArray.length);
    DataInputStream dataStream = new DataInputStream(bytesStream);
    float[] floats = new float[bytesArray.length / 4]; //float is 4 bytes. Make sure than the number of bytes can be divided by 4.
    for (int i = 0;i < floats.length; i++) {
        floats[i] = dataStream.readFloat();
    }
```

If you look at the sources of `ByteInputStream`, you will see it does not create a copy of your buffer.

`java.io.ByteInputStream`

```
public ByteArrayInputStream(byte buf[], int offset, int length) {
    this.buf = buf;
    this.pos = offset;
    this.count = Math.min(offset + length, buf.length);
    this.mark = offset;
}
```

**Update**

There will be two arrays of n bytes allocated. One array of `n` is your input byte array, and the other one is the output float array. If you do not want to allocate memory for the output array, but for example you need to access these elements one by one, then you can make an index.

```
class FloatIndex {

    private byte[] buffer;
    private ByteInputStream bytesStream;
    private int nFloats;
    private int count = 0;

    public FloatIndex(byte[] buffer) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
        ByteInputStream bytesStream = new ByteInputStream(buffer, buffer.length);
        if (buffer.length % 4 != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This buffer does not have floats");
        }
        nFloats = buffer.length / 4;
    }

    public float nextFloat() {
        DataInputStream dataStream = new DataInputStream(bytesStream);
        if (count > nFloats) {
            throw new RuntimeException("There are no more floats");
        }
        try {
            float f = dataStream.readFloat();
            count++;
            return f;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read float.", e);
        }
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return count > nFloats;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is performing a copy of the binary array, which is what I was doing already.

Comment: No, it does not make a copy of your bytes array. But it will create a new array of floats. So total memory is n bytes of your array plus n bytes of floats array = 2 * n.

Comment: Memory is allocated for the new float array, I wanted to know if it was possible for the two arrays to share the same memory space. My original approach does not create a new byte[] array either.